# Get UWP Store associations using PowerShell or MSBuild

Tags: powershell, msbuild, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm using AppVeyor CI to build my UWP app and want to create an APPX package during every build. However my `.gitignore` is ignoring the `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` and `MyAppName_StoreKey.pfx` which I want to include in the APPX package as they are identifying my app in Windows Store.

Is there any way to get these files using PowerShell or MSBuild or something like that? In other words, is there any command line equivalent to the `Project > Store > Associate App with the Store...` wizard?

I know I can upload these files to the repo as [Secure files](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/secure-files/) but I'd prefer getting the latest files from the Dev Center with every build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say probably not, as the Associate App with the Store Wizard, is an authenticated Wizard which requires a users Microsoft Account to be registered with Visual Studio, Load Credentials from storage or asking for OAuth, and then Visual Studio goes to Microsoft's server to Sign the Certificate and Sign the app with it.

AppVeyor documentation says the currently UWP is not officially supported for UWP, as a Microsoft License is required.

Edit: [Does this help?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for, since they're adding the App_TemponaryKey.pfx to the source control - I cannot do this since my app is open source. The another approach is creating the certificate using MakeCert.exe but this will probably not create the same cert as the App_StoreKey.pfx is.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to get these files using PowerShell or MSBuild or something like that? In other words, is there any command line equivalent to the Project > Store > Associate App with the Store... wizard?

No, as [@William's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423854/5254458). The associating operation needs user's interaction in Visual Studio, this doesn't depend on a public command/API.

In my experience, we need to store(maintain) the latest store association information in somewhere, overwrite the related files and replace the **reserved keywords** in the app's manifest **template** file before packaging.